# Xamarin Forms CollectionView stays empty after binding it

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created this class that creates an `ImageSource` collection `ObservableCollection<TemplateSource>`:

```
public class TemplateListViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TemplateSource> sourceList { get; set; }

    public TemplateListViewModel()
    {
        sourceList = new ObservableCollection<TemplateSource>();
        loadingTemplates += onLoadingTemplates;
        LoadTemplateList();
    }

    private event EventHandler loadingTemplates = delegate { };

    private void LoadTemplateList()
    {
        loadingTemplates(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private async void onLoadingTemplates(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        List<Template> templateList = await App.RestService.GetTemplates(App.User);

        foreach (var template in templateList)
        {
            ImageSource source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("mysite.org/myapp/" + template.FileName));
            TemplateSource templateSource = new TemplateSource { Id = template.Id, Source = source };
            sourceList.Add(templateSource);
        }
    }
}
```

And in my **XAML** I use this code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill">
        <Frame IsClippedToBounds="True" HeightRequest="45" CornerRadius="5" Padding="0" Margin="15,15,15,0" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <Entry Placeholder="Search" ReturnType="Done" PlaceholderColor="Gray" x:Name="txtSearch" Margin="5,0,0,0" TextColor="White" />
        </Frame>

        <CollectionView ItemsLayout="HorizontalList" ItemsSource="{Binding sourceList}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <ff:CachedImage
                Source="{Binding .}"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" />

                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And finally in the *page.xaml.cs* (code behind):

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    TemplateListViewModel vm = new TemplateListViewModel();
    BindingContext = vm;
    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

Now I already got help with this code from @Deczaloth, but he couldn't figure out why the `CollectionView` stays emtpy after I bind it. Now I already checked, but the `sourceList` does get filled, so thats not the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume a Collection View implementation would be faster to implement and easier to maintain/extend in the future. Think about what would happen if you decided that you need 3 columns or 1 column somewhere down the line and what would have to change. In regards to performance Xamarin [recommends Collection View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance#use-collectionview-instead-of-listview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see one potential problem in your code XD:

When you bind the `Source` property of `CachedImage` you set the binding to `"."`, but you should instead bind to the `Source` property of the `TemplateSource` class (in your context "." means a `TemplateSource` item!), that is you should change your code like so:

```
<ff:CachedImage
    Source="{Binding Source}"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
```